# System Error &H800700C1 (-2147024703) trying to compile ocx file

Tags: vb6

I am trying to compile an ocx file using File > Make {FileName.ocx}
Then it starts compiling/making ocx and then I receive this error:

[image]

```
System Error &H800700C1 (-2147024703)
```

Anyone have an idea what this error may mean? or where I can go to find out?

Comment: `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT = 193` which has the description `%1 is not a valid Win32 application.` &h800700c1 is a hResult containing a Windows error - &hc1 = 193.

Comment: based on @catcat 's comment, I wonder if your VB6 installation is damaged. Can you compile any other projects (even trivial ones) successfully?

Comment: @DaveInCaz Yes I have been able to compile other projects. This specific project does have a dependency on another ocx file that I had to manually register. My thought is maybe that ocx file is messed up but I haven't been able to figure out what to do about it yet.

Comment: Sounds like your on the right track. That other file may be corrupted.

Comment: That ended up sort of being the problem, there were two paths and was referencing the wrong path. Thank you all for your input